# About this tag for C#2.0 takes me to the C tag; URL not encoding #

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

I hovered over the `C#2.0` tag to a question and clicked `About this tag` in the menu that appears. This took me to the `C` tag "Tagged Questions" list rather than anything about `C#2.0`. Same thing happens for any `C#` tag.

Note, the URL it navigates to is https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c#2.0/info. Looks like it isn't encoding the `#`.

Google Chrome 7.0.503.0 dev.

Comment: Replicated on IE8 using XP - the encoded version of the URL works fine but leaving it as # will result in going to the C questions list.

Comment: Yup, none of the C# about links appear to be properly URL encoded.

Comment: Yep, I can reproduce this again.

Comment: @Anna, the same happens [here](http://i.imgur.com/ugqya.png) as well.

Comment: It also happens for c++ tags; for example, go to http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered, then click on the 'c++' filter tag at the right. It will then show questions marked with 'c', and also lists this tag, not c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be fixed now?

(Because Waffles fixed it :) )

Comment: Indeed, it is. :)

Answer (score 6):

> "If it was fixed, it's back again." ([link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paSZA.png))

[image]

Fixed the question-frequency links; if I missed something else, let me know (but I did a scan).