# Return URL parameter on login percent escape: C# becomes C

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

I found the following small problem. It's not that important, but it is a bug:

- I go to Stack Overflow while not logged in, and click through to the C# label
- I now find myself at [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23
- I click the login link, and go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2ftagged%2fc%23 (most of you see where this is going now)
- I login and am redirected to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#
- And that URL is the C label, not the C# one

I've seen a bunch of questions that are like this issue, but none seem to be this exact one. I expect a lot of people wish Microsoft had named it *C pound*, rather than *C sharp*.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63904/about-this-tag-for-c2-0-takes-me-to-the-c-tag-url-not-encoding

Comment: Explained here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169356/23354

Comment: btw, I realise now that your report was older, but I'd already answered on the other one; have upvoted - thanks for reporting this.