# Incorrect handling of URL-escaped characters on login

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

I found a minor bug in StackOverflow. If you are not logged into Stack Overflow and are viewing [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tagged questions, the url is as follows: /questions/tagged/c%23

When you then login into StackOverflow, and are redirected to the url previously visited, the url now is: /questions/tagged/c#

The questions you now are looking at are ones tagged with [c](/questions/tagged/c) and not [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).
I guess this is because when you are redirected it treats `%23` as `#` instead of using the actual `%23` characters.

Comment: This is the correct place for placing bugs.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Ok thanks (:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've done a little bit of research on it:

When you click `[login]` you're redirected here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2ftagged%2fc%23
```

That should actually be:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2ftagged%2fc%2523
```

In other words, the `%23` is not encoded again when used in the redirect location.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you are right: it is. The problem is that IIS and ASP.NET (in combination) [make a bit of a mess of URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913830/is-iis-performing-an-illegal-character-substitution-if-so-how-to-stop-it) if they are slightly non-trivial. There are even some pathological edge-cases where two *very different* urls inbound come back with the same `.Url` if you look at it inside ASP.NET; go figure. For example, `/x%3Fa%3Db` vs `/x?a=b`. Even though it gets *routed* correctly, both of these end up with the url saying `/x?a=b`.

It has annoyed me a few times, too, when browsing the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag only to end up back on [c](/questions/tagged/c).

The good news is: I've found some tricks that allow me to do this properly - will be deployed next build. It definitely needed fixing - it was *bad enough* for [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), but for anything international it was positively bejiggered. Thanks for giving me a nudge to fix it.

Comment: Can you share those tricks?

Comment: @CodesInChaos sure, there's nothing inherently company-specific or similar in there; how's this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117342/how-can-i-reliably-get-the-actual-url-even-when-there-are-encoded-parts-in-the/15117344#15117344

Comment: Looks like it [has returned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203116/152859)?