# Wrong return URL after logging in

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

When going to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23 and then logging in, Stack Overflow redirects me to the unencoded https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#, which effectively is the same as redirecting me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c apparently, which is not what I want, since I don't know C :-)

Should this happen? Is there a way around this? (I'm currently in [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome), but I don't think it would matter.)

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be [a regression](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168884/incorrect-handling-of-url-escaped-characters-on-login)

Comment: It's not an Chrome issue (as expected). Verified in IE10  and FF 24.0 on Win7

Comment: verified using chrome and google; will investigate (not least: that will bug me too, since my landing page includes `c%23`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, that's kinda fun; looks like `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode` broke... <s>I suspect in .NET 4.5.1</s> at some point (not sure when, where, how or why); it used to be that we could pass it `a+b#c` and get back `a%2bb%23c` - but now in returns ... `a+b#c`.

The code we have there was actually over-complicated to work around some *existing* ... "peculiarities" in some of the encoding / url APIs, but it looks like the cheese has been moved - I've compensated accordingly (it is now much simpler). I wonder what corner cases are lurking *now*...

Fixed after next deploy (so something strictly later than "2013.10.25.1554")

Comment: Don't you a Microsoft platinum support at your service for such cases of bugs in their framework? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd (chuckles quietly in a corner)

Comment: Wait... so your previous bug fix caused a new bug when the original bug in the framework was fixed??

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I would be reluctant to say that the original bug was fixed; more like it just changed a bit more. I can still reproduce craziness.

Comment: I see. Can't you just write your own custom made `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode` and be done with it once and for all? And if it works well, offer the code to Microsoft! ;)