# Bug when logging in from a URL with special characters

Tags: bug, tags, hyperlinks

If you start out from a completely vanilla state (i.e. an incognito browser session) and navigate to this url:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23
```

And then you log in (I'm using Gmail with 2-step authorization, if relevant), you are eventually redirected to this url:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#
```

Notice how the escaped hash `%23` has been decoded into an actual hash, `#`.  Since this is a special character, obviously, the effective URL is actually:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c
```

In other words, I went from looking at [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) questions to looking at [c](/questions/tagged/c) questions.  My life is not ruined, and I am able to carry on, but thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: @AakashM, ah, indeed!  And there's a circa 2010 question [linked to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63904/about-this-tag-for-c2-0-takes-me-to-the-c-tag-url-not-encoding) from that question as well.  Clearly not a high priority bug to fix. ;)